# Find boundaries for a smallest mean error

Tags: classification, neural-network, deep-learning, theano, keras

I am new at deep learning, but willing to learn.

I have this problem.

Have 5 inputs: A,B,C,D,E(columns in CSV) that gives me 1 or 0.
A,B,C,D or E can be between 0 and 100.
For example, a combination of values of these letters will give me 0 or 1.

```
A  | B | C  | D | E
20, 61, 42, 90, 3 will give me 1
20, 31, 2, 61, 20 will give me 0
```

Idea is this if A is up to 20 or less, B is up to 61 or less, C is 42 or less, D is 
90 or more and E is 3 or more, it will give me 1.

The problem number one is next, I need to find boundaries(Max and Min values) for these numbers. I do not know which column should be Max or Min. So I need to find these boundaries that will give me the smallest mean error.

The problem number two, this is more like next step, sometimes, some of the columns just do not apply to give 0 or 1, they are just relevant, so I need to find relevant columns, and set for example that column to be 100 or less, or 0 or more.

Except writing python code to load CSV, and some research regarding Logistic and Linear regressions, and other algorithms like Nearest Neiber I am kinda stuck, need advice in which direction to go. Any sample math, the code would be amazing.

Hope I have explain it good, really sorry if it is not, please let me know, and I will try to make it clearer.

Thank you.